# Black box (metaphorically)

Tags: traduction, anglais, anglicismes

1

> Computer games are a sort of a "black box" where players enter some input and get some output in return, based on rules they can't be sure of.
>
> Les jeux informatiques sont une sorte de « boîte noire » dans laquelle les joueurs entrent des entrées et obtiennent des résultats en retour, sur la base de règles dont ils ne peuvent pas être sûrs.

2

> To determine if a “black box”, a function F, is a tensor, we input vectors. If the results obey Eq. (2.4) then F must be a tensor.
>
> Pour déterminer si une « boîte noire », une fonction F, est un tenseur, nous entrons des vecteurs. Si les résultats obéissent à Eq. (2.4) alors F doit être un tenseur.

Dans des contextes comme ci-dessus peut-on utiliser en français *boîte noire*, ou son emploi est-il un anglicisme ?

Dans ce cas-ci, quelle tournure faut-il employer ?

Comment: Très bonne question. J'avoue que le seul contexte où j'emploie "boite noire" est celui d'un "enregistreur" de données, comme dans un avion par exemple. Dans les contextes techniques j'ai tendance à conserver l'anglais, mais je viendrai certainement voir les réponses afin d'employer s'il existe le terme français adéquat.

Comment: J'ai connu cette expression en anglais, où l'on m'avait alors dit que ça provenait du monde de la bande dessinée et de la caricature, dans lesquels la super machine qui a réponse à tout fut souvent représentée comme une boîte, noire, où l'on entre sa question d'un côté pour recevoir sa réponse sur un petit billet qui sort de l'autre côté de l'instrument. Cette représentation, qui évite aux auteur l'explication du processus à l'œuvre, fait probablement partie de toutes les langues de nos jours, mais peut-être l'expression n'existe-t-elle pas dans toutes les langues (?).

Comment: La source est incertaine et je ne l'ai jamais vérifiée, mais elle est du moins frappante et rationnellement très acceptable...

Comment: Pour en savoir plus sur l'origine de l'expression [en anglais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box). L'article wikipédia français sur le sujet [ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bo%C3%AEte_noire_(syst%C3%A8me)), où elle est appelée ***boîte noire*** ou ***boîte opaque***.

Comment: j'utilise aussi `boîte noire` dans ce contexte, si tu veux utiliser un adjectif à la place, tu peux dire que le fonctionnement d'un jeu est `transparent` pour l'utilisateur. Il n'a pas besoin de connaitre les algorithmes impliqués, juste de savoir quelles entrées il peut donner au jeu

Comment: Merci à tous pour le retour reçu.

Comment: @Flying_whale: Je sais que c'est souvent utilisé en informatique, mais l'usage de _transparent_ dans le sens d'_opaque_ m'a toujours laissé perplexe...

Comment: Je me suis demandé si un nom plus technique comme _dispositif_ (parce que ce ne serait pas le _monde_ ou l'_univers_, en fait ce serait ici comme le contraire d'une métaphore à mon avis, le jeu comme une sorte de _bac à sable_...) avec l'adjectif _insondable_ serait utile, en fait il aurait fallu plutôt _insondé_, aussi bien dire _mystère_ ; peut-être. Merci !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La première phrase est acceptable et idiomatique en dehors du malencontreux ***entrent des entrées***. Je suggérerais *introduisent des données* à la place et changerais aussi la fin de la phrase :

> Les jeux informatiques<sup>1</sup> sont une sorte de « boîte noire » dans laquelle les joueurs introduisent des données et de laquelle ils obtiennent des résultats en retour, sur la base de règles qu'ils ne maîtrisent pas.

En revanche, je n'utiliserai pas « boîte noire » dans la deuxième phrase :

> Pour déterminer si une fonction F dont on ne connaît pas la formule est un tenseur, nous lui fournissons des vecteurs en entrée. Si les résultats se conforment à l'équation 2.4, alors F doit être un tenseur.

<sup>1</sup><sub>On dit plutôt *les **jeux vidéo***</sub>

Answer (score 1):

C'est un anglicisme a l'origine, mais tellement repandu qu'il est tout a fait d'usage courant.